# Set placeholder argument in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql, positional-parameter

Using `psql`, it seems possible to set named arguments using `\pset somevar 'hello'`. However there appears to be no way to set a [positional argument](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) like `$1`. This makes it difficult to paste in SQL snippets that use positional arguments. In the sqlite3 CLI, it's possible to do `.param set ?1 'hello'` for this purpose. How do I do this with `psql`?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example and show the expected outcome? Also disclose your version of psql, please.

Answer (score 1):

You need [**`\set`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES) (not `\pset`!) to set ***psql*** variables.

Then you can use [SQL interpolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION) to insert those variables into SQL commands, optionally quoting your values. Demo:

```
test=> \set a 10
test=> \set foo bar
test=> \set col1 column1
test=> \set col2 'Col 2'

test=> \echo :a :'foo' :col1 :"col2"
10 'bar' column1 "Column 2"
test=> SELECT :a AS :col1, :'foo' AS :"col2";
 column1 | "Col 2" 
---------+---------
      10 | bar
(1 row)
```

Not sure how "positional arguments" come into this ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a prepared statement:

```
PREPARE stmt(integer) AS
   SELECT name FROM person WHERE id = $1;

EXECUTE stmt(42);
```